# What does "the point being" mean in this sentence?

Tags: spoken-english, parts-of-speech

I watched a Selena Gomez speech (https://youtu.be/jG-4kBIDAzA?t=120).
At 2:00, she said this below.

> When I was eleven, the point being is that when I was seven, I wanted to be an actress and I wanted to live my dream.

I am confused with the phase "the point being" and wonder why 11 became 7. Can anyone help me to understand this sentence?

Comment: She misspoke saying "when I was eleven" too soon. Rather than use a phrase that indicates you've made a mistake, such as, "or rather" or "I mean", she used a different expression. She either made a mistake, or she hoped it would sound less like she'd made a mistake in front of that adoring audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She used the phrase incorrectly while speaking extemporaneously.

The phrase is normally used to highlight a core point within a lengthier dialogue. That isn't what Selena was doing - she was correcting herself and introducing a correction. It makes no sense in that context.

It's quite common for idiomatic phrases to become overused in the speech of an individual to the point that they use them out of context. For example, an ex-manager of mine would use the phrase "*from a [x] perspective...*" to introduce *every* new thought he had. It was extremely irritating! Funnily enough, a commonly overused phrase is "*I mean to say...*", which some people overuse to the point of beginning every sentence with it, but actually, that would have been the perfect phrase for Selena to correct herself with.